# Why Kotlin/Java doesn't have an option for preemptive scheduler?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, jvm

Heavy CPU bound task could block the thread and delay other tasks waiting execution. That's because JVM can't interrupt running thread and require help from programmer and manual interruption.

So writing CPU bound tasks in Java/Kotlin requires manual intervention to make things run smoothly, like using `Sequence` in Kotlin in code below.

```
fun simple(): Sequence<Int> = sequence { // sequence builder
    for (i in 1..3) {
        Thread.sleep(100) // pretend we are computing it
        yield(i) // yield next value
    }
}

fun main() {
    simple().forEach { value -> println(value) } 
}
```

As far as I understood the reason is that having preemptive scheduler with the ability to interrupt running threads have performance overhead.

But wouldn't it be better to have a switch, so you can choose? If you would like to run JVM with faster non-preemptive scheduler. Or with slower pre-emtpive (interrupting and switching the tread after N instructions) one but able to run things smoothly and don't require manual labor to do that?

I wonder why Java/Kotlin doesn't have such JVM switch that would allow to choose what mode you would like.

Comment: JVM can't interrupt running thread, but O/S can. JVM need not to bother. And user need not to program intervention. If a heavy CPU bound task blocks a thread, then simply create another thread and thus do not delay other tasks.

Comment: This code example has nothing to do with scheduling. It’s a simple single-threaded code construct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you program using Kotlin coroutines or Java virtual threads (after Loom), you *get* preemptive scheduling from the OS.

Following usual practices, tasks that are not blocked (i.e., they need CPU) are multiplexed over real OS threads in the Kotlin default dispatcher or Java ForkJoinPool.  Those OS threads are scheduled preemptively by the OS.

Unlike old-style multithreading, however, tasks are not assigned to a thread when they are blocked waiting for I/O.  This makes *no difference* in terms of preemption, since a task that is waiting for I/O couldn't possibly preempt another running task anyway.

What you *don't* get when programming with coroutines, is preemptive scheduling over a large number of tasks simultaneously.  If you have many tasks that require the CPU, then the first N will be assigned to a real thread and the OS will time slice them.  The remaining ones will wait in the queue until those ones are done.

But in real life, when you have 10000 tasks that need to be simultaneously *interactive*, they are I/O bound tasks.  On average, there aren't many that require the CPU at any one time, so the number of real threads you get from the default dispatcher or ForkJoinPool is plenty.  *In normal operation, the queue of tasks waiting for threads is almost always empty.*

If you really had a situation where 10000 *CPU-bound* tasks needed to be simultaneously interactive, well, then you would be sad anyway, because time slicing would not provide a very smooth experience.

Comment: In modern CSP Programming Model, a technology which applies pre-emptive scheduling on Co-routines (which means, in user mode) has an edge over "OS-Threads doing it". In later case, you apply extra Mutex/Locks in user mode for Isolation which make calls to OS/Kernel; not performant at scale.

Scalable / Performant Architecture: Use of OS-Process for (natural) isolation, not OS-Threads, and use of pre-emption on co-routines (in user mode), just like in OpenSwoole (which is a PHP Processing engine, whichi s an alternate to PHP-FPM engine).

Answer (score 5):

This question is based on a false premise: **In the JVM, a preemptive scheduler is your only choice.** No modern JVM uses co-operative multitasking.

No modern JVM implements user space threads or a scheduler of its own. JVMs use native operating system threads instead. Native threads are scheduled by the operating system, and operating system schedulers *are* preemptive.

The fact that JVM threads map 1-to-1 to native operating system threads is a problem for applications that need a high level of concurrency. Threads are relatively scarce and expensive. To address this, [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) is investigating adding "virtual threads" that may allow using native threads more sparingly, especially for I/O bound tasks.

Project Loom is under active development and there is no set schedule of when it will become a part of standard Java. Regarding how Project Loom schedules "virtual threads", the [latest (May 2020) update](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html#scheduling) from Project Loom claims *"virtual threads are preemptive, not cooperative"* but then goes on to say *"none of the schedulers in the JDK currently employs time-slice-based preemption of virtual threads"*. It sounds like in its current state the "virtual thread" scheduler in Project Loom is somewhere between fully co-operative and fully pre-emptive. It will be interesting to see how the project develops and what we will get when it is integrated into main stream Java.

In a [July 28 Q&A the Loom project lead Ron Pressler](https://youtu.be/23HjZBOIshY?t=2306) mentioned that you will be able to plug in a scheduler of your own for virtual thread, but did not go into details of how much control you get over the scheduling algorithm.

Comment: Is this true of [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main)?

Comment: But it could provide an option of using its own, slower threads, with preemptive scheduler, additionally to default native threads.

Comment: @jaco0646 I've added a note on project loom. Note that Loom will not change the existing threads, instead it adds a new "virtual thread" concept.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Why should the JVM include a *worse* implementation of something that the operating system already provides?

Comment: @Joni if I had to write less and the code would be simpler (as would be possible with Erlang-like preemptive threads and scheduler), even if there will be some performance lost - I don't see that as worse. Especially if there's an option and I can choose which one I prefer.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Why do you say you would have to write less code? Did you miss the fact that the *operating system scheduler is pre-emptive*?

Comment: @Joni but inside the JVM the threads won't be switched right? So Java thread with heavy CPU code - would prevent other Java code from running on Thread, until the first one is finished.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin that is not correct. The operating system scheduler interrupts each thread when their time slice is up, and evaluates the need to switch to another task.

Comment: ^ this, Plus I'd argue that there's a point where if you need more performance, you're on the wrong language.

Comment: To be fair, Java programmers use cooperative multitasking all the time, with ForkJoinPool or another ExecutorService as the scheduler.  Sometimes in an event-driven style, sometimes in the monadic style with CompletableFuture, and later in the coroutine style with project Loom.

Comment: @MattTimmermans That sounds like a confusion of concepts. ExecutorService is not a multitasking scheduler. A multitasking scheduler should allow you to run more than one task concurrently, not one after another, using a single processor. An ExecutorService with a single "processor" (thread) can only run tasks one after another.

Comment: We had multitasking before we had multiple CPUs.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes, that is exactly my point. Multitasking allows you to run more than one task concurrently using one single CPU.

Comment: Manually dividing a task up into units that can be interleaved with the units of other tasks is exactly what cooperative multitasking is.  The scheduler is exactly the thing that orders those interleaved units.  I think you're the one who is confusing concepts.

Comment: @MattTimmermans That does not sound like cooperative multitasking to me. You don't "manually divide a task up into units". Instead, the task, which runs as a single unit, voluntarily "yields" control back to the scheduler. The scheduler may decide to switch to running another task. I suppose you *could* implement some kind of a cooperative multitasking scheduler framework on top of a Java ExecutorService, but that's akin to saying that using a while loop is cooperative multitasking.

Comment: Lets say you write a nodeJS server that can serve multiple simultaneous requests in a single thread... would you really say that it is not multitasking in that thread?  Do you think it depends on whether you used async/await or used promises directly?

Comment: Maybe an appeal to authority will help: https://www.google.com/search?q=project+loom+scheduler+forkjoinpool&oq=project+loom+scheduler+forkjoinpool

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of nodejs, but I was under the impression it's just an event loop. How do you define "task" in nodejs and does nodejs have the capability of running multiple "tasks" concurrently? Also, why bring up nodejs in a conversation that has been about Java and the JVM until now? And, can you clarify what point you're making by posting a link to Google?

Comment: "...Instead, the task, which runs as a single unit, voluntarily "yields" control back to the scheduler..." - that's why preemptive scheduler is more smooth, as it doesn't require voluntarism and will "force" the task into cooperation after N CPU instructions (called N reductions in Erlang) :). Erlang (preemptive) works that way. Node.JS (cooperative) - does not, you have to give up control on CPU heavy calculations to let other async blocks to have its CPU share.